# 7Zip command line: Add without directory attribute D

Tags: command-line, zip, 7-zip

I would like to add all files within a folder including all files in all subdirs with their paths to a zip archive.
So this seems to be just a normal recursive add, but I need directories to be added without the D attribute.
I know this can be achieved within a zip file, but how to do that with 7zip?

Here is a screenshot of an archive with the D:

[image: zip with D]

And here is one without the D:

[image: zip without D]

Comment: How is a directory without the D attribute even supposed to work? Are you referring to `zip --no-dir-entries` which doesn't include directories _at all_?

Comment: I don't know about zip --no-dir-entries.

Comment: But I can create both zip archives posted above with 7Zip. The one without the D is created with the parameter -ir!dir\*.* but this excludes directories with a dot as well as files without a dot.

Comment: While forcing to store or not the whole directiry structure it affects on storing empty folders only, it seems... when not stored, folder structure is restored from forder chains stored as a parts of full filenames, so empy folders are lost.

Comment: Yes, regardless of method, you're seeing that because the directory-entries are not stored _at all_. The browser shows virtual entries because it has to show something. Notice how they don't have timestamps or _any_ other metadata, not just the D attribute.

Comment: Ok, great. So how can I achieve this?